# PHP not escaping when using json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json, serialization

I have an HTML form with text fields, that I'm trying to post into a MySQL blob as JSON data, to be retrieved back into a PHP array (for repopulating the fields etc.)
However, the JSON string seems to be ignoring the default of escaping "illegal" characters.
When it tries to decode the JSON, it's causing the array to be empty.  My code:

```
if ($_POST) {
$_POST = json_encode($_POST);

$query = "REPLACE INTO `$form` (`jsonresults`) VALUES ('$_POST') ";
$stm = $pdo->prepare("$query");
$stm->execute();
```

Array is then decoded with:

```
$dbresults = json_decode($dbresults['jsonresults'], true);
```

This works fine with text that doesn't have special characters, but when " or ' is added etc. it causes the error.  Looking in the database, the JSON doesn't appear to have escaped any special characters, even though it apparently should do this by default (unless using JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, which I'm not).

I've also tried the following (separately of course):

```
$_POST = json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode', $_POST));
$_POST = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($_POST), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$_POST = serialize($_POST);
```

all with similar problems. 
Once the array is "decoded", special characters break it and cause it to be empty or invalid.

Can anyone suggest why this isn't working, or what is the best way to store and retrieve a PHP array in a MySQL database (without using individual DB fields for each text input, I have hundreds on this page).

Comment: Have you tried `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or the PDO equivalent?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes added by `json_encode` are escaped for JSON.  The database interprets these as escapes for the database and so the slashes do not persist in the data unless they are also escaped.  Use a prepared statement:

```
$_POST = json_encode($_POST);
$query = "REPLACE INTO `$form` (`jsonresults`) VALUES (:json)";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stm->bindParam(':json', $_POST, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();
```

Comment: This should be the flow https://3v4l.org/g6gEN you may need to edit your question or ask a new one with the actual input and output at the different stages.

Comment: Thanks.  This is kind of working, but if a double quote is entered into the text field of the web page, it still messes up the data.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the data is intact and pulls successfully into the PHP array now.  But when I try and display it with PHP dynamically generating the HTML, it truncates:
<input id=\"whatever\" name=\"$name\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"$inputtype\" value=\"" . $dbresult['arraykey]' . "\" $max required />. Apologies, I know this has gone a bit above and beyond the original question.  I appreciate your help, and I've got a lot further already.  I guess the double quotes are throwing the HTML/PHP off now.

Comment: Why overwrite superglobal `$_POST`?

Comment: `htmlentities` the data before putting in the `"` for the input value.  How would this work `value="some "data" here"`

Comment: @AbraCadaver That did it!  Thank you so much!   :D  I massively appreciate your help with this.  Sometimes you can go round in circles without another pair of eyes.